# Подсчитать размер массива полученного от MySQL

Tags: массивы, php, алгоритм, mysql

**День добрый.**

Задача:

Получив выборку из базы обычным способом`(SELECT * FROM table WHERE param=12)` в переменную `$result`, необходимо подсчитать количество строк полученных из базы.
Без применения `*foreach*. count(array)` - как Вы поняли не считает таковой массив.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Предположим что запрос у нас `$query = mysql_query(...`

`$num_rows = mysql_num_rows($query);`

`echo $num_rows;`

в новом php7 все тоже самое только функции называются mysqli_query и  mysqli_num_rows соответственно.

Answer (score 1):

```
$mysqli_result = $mysqli->query(SELECT * FROM table WHERE param=12);
print($mysqli_result->num_rows);
```

должно помочь.

Comment: Боюсь что ТС еще не дорос до mysqli)

Comment: Боюсь, если я опять напишу решение с mysql, опять придет @eicto и надает по шапке. Что самое обидное - правильно сделает.

Comment: тогда почему не PDO? Думаю ответ должен быть понятен ТС'у а не нравиться @eicto :D)

Comment: Не PDO, потому что тут есть железная отмазка: он далеко не везде стоит :)
Ответ должен быть понятен ТС, но он не должен с первых дней жизни уводить вникуда. Очень многие до сих пор на сайтах советуют конструкцию 
mysql_connect or die(), хотя она самая простая, она далеко не самая правильная. Даже тот же 

    if(mysql_connect()){}else{ show_page_try_again_later()};

В разы лучше, но не такой сложный, как эксепшены.